# Spectral family associated with the Laplacian operator in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-transform, functional-equations

Let $\lambda>0$ be given. Define
$$G_{\lambda}(\xi) = \chi_{_{\lbrace |\xi|^{2} \leq \lambda \rbrace }}.
$$
and
$$
E_{0}(\lambda)f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[G_{\lambda}(|\xi|^{2})\mathcal{F}(f)], \ \ f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})
$$
How do I show that

$$(E_{0}(\lambda)f|f) = \|E_{0}(\lambda)f\|^{2}_{L^{2}}, \ \ f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\qquad ?$$

Comment: The identity says that $E_0$ is a projection, and this is true because (multiplication by) $G_{\lambda}$ is a projection and the Fourier transform is unitary.

Comment: I think your question would have been more suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @ChristianRemling I don't care which site I ask my question on

Comment: AGL, but some other people _do_ care, and @ChristianRemling's point is that you would receive more positive reception for this question on math.stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identity amounts to
$$\frac12(E_0(\lambda)^*+E_0(\lambda))=E_0^*(\lambda) E_0(\lambda).$$
Since ${\cal F}^*=\cal F$, this is equivalent to saying that $$\frac12(G_\lambda+\overline{G}_\lambda)=|G_\lambda|^2,$$
which is true because $G_\lambda(\xi)$ equals either $0$ or $1$.

**Edit**. To explain the first equality, let us define the bounded linear operator
$$L:=E_0(\lambda)-E_0^*(\lambda) E_0(\lambda).$$
Your assumption is that $(Lf\mid f)=0$ for every $f$, which means that $L^*+L=0$.

Comment: I didn't understand the first equality, I'm sorry

Comment: @AGL. I edited my answer, to explain this equality.

Comment: How do I show that $\lambda \to \|E_{0}(\lambda)f\|^{2}_{L^{2}}$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424448/lambda-to-e-0-lambdaf-2-l2-is-absolutely-continuous